# how do you use jq to create a columns based on objects and list other objects from same array under it for json to convert to csv?

Tags: json, csv, multiple-columns, jq

Good day Community,

I am new to jq and I am trying to use it as a tool to covert json output to csv.

I have the following situation.  I would like to take json data listed below and covert it to a nicely formatted csv file for other editing and auditing processes out side the format of what json can offer.

I have the following json data:

```
{
"enrollments": [
    {
        "adminContact": {
            "email": "admin@domain.com",
            "firstName": "john",
            "lastName": "doe",
            "phone": "555-555-5555"
        },
        "certificateType": "third-party",
        "changeManagement": true,
        "csr": {
            "c": "US",
            "cn": "www.column.com",
            "l": "Houston",
            "o": "A Company International Ltd.",
            "ou": "Technology and Operations Services",
            "sans": [
                "example1.com",
                "example2.com",
                "example3.com",
                "example4.com"
            ],
            "st": "Bermingham"
        }
    },
    {
        "adminContact": {
            "email": "admin@domain.com",
            "firstName": "john",
            "lastName": "doe",
            "phone": "555-555-5555"
        },
        "certificateType": "third-party",
        "changeManagement": true,
        "csr": {
            "c": "US",
            "cn": "www.column2.com",
            "l": "Houston",
            "o": "A Company International Ltd.",
            "ou": "Technology and Operations Services",
            "sans": [
                "www.example1.com",
                "www.example2.com",
                "www.example3.com",
                "www.example4.com"
            ],
            "st": "Bermingham"
        },
        "certificateType": "third-party",
        "changeManagement": true,
        "csr": {
            "c": "US",
            "cn": "www.column-other-additional-iterations.com",
            "l": "Houston",
            "o": "A Company International Ltd.",
            "ou": "Technology and Operations Services",
            "sans": [
                "www.example-to-infinite1.com",
                "www.example-to-infinite2.com",
                "www.example-to-infinite3.com",
                "www.example-to-infinite4.com"
            ],
            "st": "Bermingham"
    }
]
}
```

My goal is to to covert it to a .csv file in the following format.  I would like to be able to grab any occurrence of "cn" and their corresponding "SANs" to iterate it across and create their individual columns, respectively:

```
Common Name      SANS            Common Name      SANS             => iterate
www.column.com   example1.com    www.column2.com  www.example1.com
                 example2.com                     www.example2.com
                 example3.com                     www.example3.com
                 example4.com                     www.example4.com
```

What I have been able to do so far:

```
jq -r '.enrollments[].csr | {cn: .cn, sans: .sans[]}  | [.cn, .sans] |@csv' certs.json > test.csv
```

And it gives me the following output:

```
"www.column.com","example1.com"
"www.column.com","example2.com"
"www.column.com","example3.com"
"www.column.com","example4.com"
"www.column2.com","www.example1.com"
"www.column2.com","www.example2.com"
"www.column2.com","www.example3.com"
"www.column2.com","www.example4.com"
...iterate through all records of the same type of data that occurs
```

So, I was able to link the "cn" object to the "sans" array.

If the desired format I listed above is not possible, would the following output work?

```
Common Name      SANS
www.column.com   example1.com
www.column.com   example2.com
www.column.com   example3.com
www.column.com   example4.com
www.column2.com  www.example1.com
www.column2.com  www.example2.com
www.column2.com  www.example3.com
www.column2.com  www.example4.com
...iterate through all records of the same type of data that occurs
```

When I have been researching online I came across some techniques that others were working with but I have not been able to find a solution yet.

For the column names, i have been playing around with this within the command.  however, everything I have tried to incorporate this doesnt seem to work:

```
(["Common Name"] + ["SANS"]),
```

In addition, a lot of posts are saying to work with the map function.

```
jq --raw-output '(map(keys) | add | unique) as $cols | map(. as $row | $cols | map($row[.])) as $rows | $cols, $rows[] | @csv'
```

and I get the following output:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:51): object ({"adminCont...) is not valid in a csv row
0,1

exit status 5
```

It looked like it got stuck on the first object, I am not sure if the "{" is what the programming is erroring out on but I then tried the following.  I tried to replace the areas where the "^" are with different paths in hopes to having the program find what I am looking for:

```
jq --raw-output '(map(keys) | add | unique) as $cols | map(. as $row | $cols | map($row[.])) as $rows | 
                      ^                                    ^                            ^
$cols, $rows[] | @csv'
```

paths i have tried replacing it with are the following, respectively:

```
.enrollments[].csr
.csr.cn
.csr.sans
```

At this point I am not sure and decided to reach out to the community.  Again, I am new to jq and I am trying to find the connections, relationships, and learn the logic here.  I am open to any suggestions, advice, and/or if there is a better way to capture this information. I am also open to other methods or best practices for using another format output to go with instead.

I apologize in advance if a similar post of this nature already exists as I was not able to find it in my searches.  If so, please let me know and I will follow the community guidelines to edit or remove this post.

Your help is much appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: If the real goal is to audit and edit the JSON, would it not perhaps be better to use jq to perform the auditing and editing?

Answer (score 1):

The requested format is a bit odd in a couple of respects, so let's start with a simpler and perhaps more useful goal -- to produce a more regular format:

```
www.column.com  example1.com    www.column2.com www.example1.com
www.column.com  example2.com    www.column2.com www.example2.com
www.column.com  example3.com    www.column2.com www.example3.com
www.column.com  example4.com    www.column2.com www.example4.com
```

This can be done using the filter:

```
[ [.enrollments[0].csr |  {cn, sans: .sans[]} | [.cn, .sans] ],
  [.enrollments[1].csr |  {cn, sans: .sans[]} | [.cn, .sans] ] ]
| transpose
| map(add)
| .[]
| @csv
```

### Blanking out the first and third columns in all but the first row

The requested format is now readily obtained by tweaking the above jq program so that it becomes:

```
[ [.enrollments[0].csr |  {cn, sans: .sans[]} | [.cn, .sans] ],
  [.enrollments[1].csr |  {cn, sans: .sans[]} | [.cn, .sans] ] ]
| transpose
| map(add)
| (.[0],
   (.[1:][] | (.[2] = "" | .[0] = "" )))
| @csv
```

### Generic approach

The first program above can be generalized to allow the "enrollments" array to be arbitrarily long as follows:

```
[ .enrollments[]
  | [ .csr |  {cn, sans: .sans[]} | [.cn, .sans] ]]
| transpose
| map(add)
| .[]
| @tsv
```

This can also be modified as before to blank out the values in all but the first row.

Comment: this is amazing.  real quick question, what if there is multiple objects in the enrollments array?  will i have to manually number them all? i.e. .enrollments[1...50].csr, etc.  btw, if the requested format is a bit odd, would there be a more logical format you would recommend?

Comment: Regarding the array, please see the update.  Regarding the odd format, I don't understand the real problem so at this point I don't have anything to add.

Comment: hello @peak.  sorry for the confusion, you mentioned that my question in regards to the desired format i was asking about was odd, so I was inquiring if you had any better way of retrieving the formation I was trying to grab.  I have updated the question as you specified.  What I was wondering if there are other occurrences of the same type of data, is there a way of collecting them all. currently when playing with your commands, it grabs all the cn and sans and puts them into only two columns which are the [0] and [1] occurrences.  I thought using .[0] would grab all but it didnt work.